# Redisson client - thread safe

Tags: multithreading, redis, redisson

Is the redisson client thread-safe? In my application, I would like to maintain one client object and let all the threads use this to get/put to Redis. In the config, there are two parameters `threads` and `nettyThreads`. Do these parameters help create a connection pool? If yes, which among these should I use if my use-case is primarily simple get/put operations on Redisson objects?

Also, are these connections active throughout the life of the RedissonClient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redisson client and all of its objects are thread safe. `threads` and `nettyThreads` are configuration for the internal thread pools.

Since netty uses event loop model that is similar to the way Redis works internally, you don't need a great deal of threads. The default value is twice the number of your processor cores, assuming you have hyper-thread or equivalent technology enabled. I would advise to start on the default value and see how you are getting on.